# Schema modifcation lock by background process PERSISTED_VERSIO

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to modify the schema of a table in azure sql database and it is getting blocked by a background process. When I run sp_who I see the cmd as 'PERSISTED_VERSIO' for this background process and I cannot figure out what this is. I stopped all applications that are trying to access this database with no lock. Anyone know what this is?
When I try to kill this process I get a message saying this is not an active process.

Edit 7/17/2018: This appears to be an issue with Azure db platform. The process fullname is PERSISTED_VERSION_CLEANER (found using select * from sys.dm_exec_requests).

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround try scaling up the database to a new tier, when finished, you can scale down to the original service tier assigned to the database, then retry the database schema modification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's not related to the resources. DTU utilization is not high when this happens. Schema modification is just getting locked by that PERSISTED_VERSIO

Comment: I am not talking DTU resources. What happens when you scale up/down can unlock the database. Just try it.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have helped but I had to run the schema change immediately. Otherwise the PERSISTED_VERSIO comes back and locks up any other schema changes. Looks like I have to do this for each schema change separately.

Comment: Let me investigate when that PERSISTED_VERSIO occurs and come back to you. Meanwhile please use this workaround. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I have contacted Azure support and they seem to have fixed it already. I don't see it anymore. Definitely would help to find out why this process is running.

Answer (score -1):

I too ran into it earlier today.
Scale up/down causes the DB to be copied/restarted to a different HW. 
Restarting DB using DBCC Stackdump is easy workaround in this case.